# How to fix side banner image without scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page, in that having 2 images 1 each on both side as side wall with width 190px and height 700px. I want both images to be fixed without scrolling. I have given style as position fixed to both image then 1 image getting vanished and right side image comes to left end.how can solve this problem can anybody help. the program code is given below

**HTML**

```
    <div id="left-ad">
        <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="#" ><img src="sidewall.png" alt="Call UAE offline Business Directory" style="border-width: 0px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-ad" >
        <a href="#" ><img src="wad.jpg" alt="Call UAE" style="border-width: 0px" ></a>
    </div>
    <div class=wrapper>
        //center body part
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left-ad{
float:left;       
position: fixed;
}

.right-ad{
float:right;
position: fixed;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute to place them on the right. They will stay there when you scroll too.

```
  .right-ad{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 150px; //change this to how far you want it down the page
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Float does not work with position fixed elements. you can use **left** and **right** properties to make that happen

```
#left-ad{
  left:0;       
  position: fixed;
}

.right-ad{
  right:0;
  position: fixed;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy... its a great help ...Thank you very much

Comment: If my answer fixed your issue, please mark it as accepted. That would be helpful for future referring user. Thanks.